# Управление ресурсами в HiveOnTez

Tags: hadoop, map-reduce, hive

У меня есть хадуп и hiveOnTez - я пользователь (не админ, не сопровожденец и тд).
Подключаюсь к хайву через dbeaver.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для технической учетки под которой я хожу выделено 8 рам и 4 ядра, из них 4 рам и 2 ядра на АМ.

1. Не суть важно на тез или на мр, но можно ли явно регулировать количество ядер и памяти на каждый запрос ? Тоже по синтаксису и в принципе как это осуществить ничего не нашла
2. Всего имеем 4 ядра 8 рам, на ам выделено 2/4 соответственно, почему то при выполнении запросов используется максимум 2 ядра 8 рам, ещё 2 ядра простаивают в любой ситуации, как принудительно  взять их в работу? Или я чего-то не понимаю? Почему в demand resources пишет 3 ядра, но не использует их?

С данными вопросами в сопровождение хадупа своей компании обращалась, получила ответ, что раз не использует - значит не нужно. На вопрос, так вот же написано деманд ресурсес - сказали **не нужно**.

Ответы на возможные вопросы:
-нет, больше ресурсов нам выделить не могут.
-нет, убрать хайв в принципе и сидеть на hdfs мы не можем. Сменить движок для просмотра данных в теории можем.